# Matching a string formatted like a list

Tags: python, regex

I am reading data from a csv file that has a column that has data with the following format:

```
['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Backup Camera', 'Heated Seats']
```

Originally I tried to parse it like a list but it is actually just a string so I need a way to extract the actual values from this string.

I'm thinking the best way to do it would be to use regex (unless I'm wrong here).

I'm not great at regex so I came up with something like this:

```
[a-zA-Z\s]*
```

and tested it on https://regex101.com/ but I'm finding that it creates blank space matches as well, not just for the characters defined in the [].

How would I clean this up to only match with the a-zA-Z characters enclosed by the ''?

Comment: If your string really is a syntactically valid representation of a Python list, then drop the regex approach and instead use `ast.literal_eval()` to interpret it.

Comment: Yup, you were right. The `ast` library is a much better way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dead set on regex and the input is well-formed (read as doesn't contain an escaped single quote) this should suffice:

```py
import re
list_str = "['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Backup Camera', 'Heated Seats']"

# match any characters between single quotes in a non-greedy fashion
regex = r"'(.*?)'"    

matches = re.findall(regex, list_str)
# matches = ['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Backup Camera', 'Heated Seats']
```

Other options include:

- parse the string using `ast.literal_eval()` (credit @BoarGules)
- read the string using `json.loads` the caveat here is that single quotes must be replaced with double quotes prior to passing the string to `json.loads`

code for the json module solution:

```py
import json

list_str = "['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Backup Camera', 'Heated Seats']"

as_list = json.loads(list_str.replace("'", '"'))
```

code for ast solution:

```py
import ast
list_str = "['Alloy Wheels', 'Bluetooth', 'Backup Camera', 'Heated Seats']"
as_list = ast.literal_eval(list_str)
```

Comment: Great, the `ast.literal_eval()` method is a much simpler way of doing this compared to what I was originally trying. Thanks.